# What should be the path of file in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Code -

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('sample.mp4')
```

for above code where sample.mp4 should be? (Absolute path is not working, Absolute Path : H:\sample.mp4

Answer (score 0):

The file should be in your "working directory", the directory from which you run your Python script. Most likely, putting "sample.mp4" in the same directory as your script and running your script from there should work.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute paths work. You need to give them either as raw string ( r“c:\test“) or with escaped backslashes (”c: \\test“).

Otherwise backslashes might mean an escape sequence (such as tab in y case, or \n for newline)

And probably even better: take the path as argument via sys.argv or argparse module, because being able to pass the path makes your script more flexible.

Comment: tried using argparse and print the path but it displays None

Comment: Code - 
import argparse
a = argparse.ArgumentParser()
a.add_argument("--pathIn", help="H:\\sample.mp4")
args = a.parse_args()
print(args)

Output - 
Namespace(pathIn=None)

Comment: I’m sorry, but of course absolute paths are working. There is only two options: relative path to the current working directory, or absolute paths. Opencv does not have any path convention beyond that whatsoever. So either your paths are malformed (eg due to not being escaped properly) or the file is corrupt or at least not understood by opencv. Then it’s not a path but format question anymore. Please show the actual error message.

Comment: So what then is happening? You need to describe you Problem better, this is not 20 questions.